# ToolTwist Controller running ruby file in terminal - Fatal error: Unknown payload

Tags: ruby, bash, tooltwist

I'm trying to run a ruby file that will show git version of a particular payload but I'm getting the following error:

```
**
** Fatal error: Unknown payload webdesign/gmd.
**

- removing /launchpads/controllerTest/build.xml.
- removing /launchpads/controllerTest/CONFIG_SUMMARY.
```

my command:

```
ruby checkLaunchpad.rb --show-payload-versions controllerTest webdesign gmd
```

I'm also getting same error when `--update-payload-cache` option was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to ruby scripts from the ToolTwist Controller are run from the command line, it is necessary to first set the appropriate environment variables. Normally this is done by running a command something like:

> $ .  /ControllerV8/setParams

This will set TTC_DEPLOY and TTC_CONFIG, which are used by checkLaunchpad.rb.

*(note the space between the . (dot) and the filename.)*